# How to make 1:1 ratio video in Davinci Resolve?

Tags: davinci-resolve

I want to make 1:1 ratio Instagram videos using Davinci Resolve. But I am unable to find how to change the aspect ratio to 1:1 using Davinci Resolve.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by going to File>Project Settings...  Under the Master Settings tab on Timeline resolution choose Custom and change For 1920x1080 processing to For 1080x1080 processing.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to make a 1080x1080 (1:1) and import your 1920x1080 footage (I'm assuming) and scale the footage to your liking. You either can use part of the footage (crop to fill 1:1), or fit the whole 1920x1080p video within the 1:1 ratio square (it will show black bars).

edit: look at this video for Davinci Resolve Image Scaling...

[Look into image scaling preset in Project settings / also click here for DaVinci Resolve tutorial.](https://youtu.be/gAPrg7jykTg?t=1m48s)

To change the scale of your video/images in the Edit Page, you'll need to open up the Inspector (top-right corner)

Comment: Link's broken.  I agree with your answer, but I would encourage you to provide specific steps and not rely on external links.  DaVinci's UI is not very friendly or intuitive.  So, for example, instead of just "make a 1080x1080," something like "make your timeline 1080x1080 by entering  those values in the 'for processing' field of the 'Timeline Format' section of the 'Master Settings' tab of the project settings. Also, be sure to click 'Don't Change' when prompted."

Comment: The link is not broken, you just have to copy and paste it. Next time I will include that in my directions.

Comment: Copying and pasting in my browser doesn't work either.

Comment: When you're copying links from youtube, you should copy the one from youtube's "share" button.  It will look something like 'h t t p s ://youtu.be/XXXXXXXXXXX'.  Then to make the link inline on stack exchange, use the icon that looks like two links of chain, just to the right of the italics icon.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't realized that you are new here.  Welcome to Video Production Stack Exchange!  You should be able to edit your answer by clicking the "edit" button below it.  Although, to be honest, I don't remember if you need to earn more reputation first.  I can edit it if you want me to, I just need to know what video you were trying to link to.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the link, but the original question is about Davinci Resolve, and the link you've supplied is for Premiere.